# Selecting only part of a string with wildcard (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to only select part of a URL string, using wildcards.

Example:

```
https://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enAU787AU788&ei=9N6_W5o5w-b4BrKTvsgE&q=stackoverflow&oq=stackoverflow&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131i67k1j0l4j0i10k1j0l4.427511.429162.0.429260.13.8.0.0.0.0.314.525.2-1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..11.2.524....0.NEXVTCFK4GA
```

The wildcard for this is `%//%/%`

I only want to select %//**%**/% (The bolded section). This needs to be done for any given URL under the same format.

How can I use substring, replace, charindex do do this?

Or are there any alternative methods of doing this?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But well: I think your requirements are unclear. Are you sure that your URLs look like that? Maybe you should rather describe what the actual problem is you intend to solve here.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
DECLARE @urls TABLE (urlId INT IDENTITY, urlText VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL);
INSERT @urls(urlText)
VALUES
('https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Server-MVP-Deep-Dives/dp/1617290475'),
('http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function.aspx'),
('http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2015/04/26/non-parallelizable-operations-in-sql-server.aspx'),
('http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/04/29/functions-io-statistics-and-the-execution-plan/'),
('https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/sql-server-functions-dragging-query/');

SELECT urlId   = u.urlId, 
       urlText = u.urlText, 
       [url]   = SUBSTRING(u.urlText,front.pos,txt.ln)
FROM @urls AS u
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('//',u.urlText)+2)) AS front(pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('/',u.urlText,front.pos)-front.pos)) AS txt(ln);
```

**Results:**

```
urlId   urlText                                                 url
------- ------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------
1       https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Server-MVP-Deep-Dives/dp...  www.amazon.com
2       http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11...  sqlblog.com
3       http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2015/0...  sqlblogcasts.com
4       http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/04/29/...  www.sqlinthewild.co.za
5       https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/sql-serve...  www.brentozar.com
```